# AJAX pagination in Laravel 7 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, pagination

I am using Laravel 7 and I want to use ajax for my pagination so that it would not refresh the whole page when I click for the next page. I searched up to solve my problem but it was not working and it would not go to the fetch() whenever I error_log() in controller. Whenever I click on page 2 it would error. In the  console the error shown is:

```
app.js:16437 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/ledger/fetch?page=2 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

In the storage/logs/laravel.log

```
[previous exception] [object] (BadMethodCallException(code: 0): Method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Collection::links does not exist. at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\final_Financial\\fin_book_09\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Support\\Traits\\Macroable.php:103)
```

**LedgerController.php**

```
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $disableLedger = true;
        $ledger = Ledger::orderBy('id', 'DESC')
            ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
            ->paginate(5);
        $ledgerCatType = DB::table('ledgers')
            ->orderBy('ledgers.id', 'DESC')
            ->join('categories', 'ledgers.cat_id', '=', 'categories.id')
            ->where('ledgers.user_id', auth()->user()->id)
            ->get('categories.type');
        $category = Category::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->get();
        return view('ledgers.index', [
            'ledgers' => $ledger,
            'categories' => $category,
            'disableLedger' => $disableLedger,
            'ledgerCatType' => $ledgerCatType
        ]);
    }
```

```
    function fetch(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax())
        {
            $ledger = Ledger::orderBy('id', 'DESC')
                ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
                ->paginate(5);
            $ledgerCatType = DB::table('ledgers')
                ->orderBy('ledgers.id', 'DESC')
                ->join('categories', 'ledgers.cat_id', '=', 'categories.id')
                ->where('ledgers.user_id', auth()->user()->id)
                ->get('categories.type');
            $category = Category::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->get();
            return view('ledger.entries', compact('ledger', 'categories', 'ledgerCatType'))->render();
        }
    }
```

**script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.pagination a').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var page = $(this).attr('href').split('page=')[1];
        fetch(page);
    })
    function fetch(page) {
        $.ajax({
            url : '/ledger/fetch?page='+page,
            success : function(data)
            {
                $('#ledger-entry').html(data);
            },
            error : function(){ 
                alert("error!!!!");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

under the folder ledgers which will be called in the index.blade.php
**entries.blade.php**

```
<div class="outer-cont">
    <table class="table container inner-cont">
        <thead>
            <th scope="col">Date</th>
            <th scope="col">Description</th>
            <th scope="col">Category</th>
            <th scope="col">Amount</th>
            <th scope="col"></th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for($i = 0; $i < count($ledgers); $i++)
            <tr scope="row">
                <td class="tbl-date">{{ $ledgers[$i]->month }} {{ $ledgers[$i]->day }}, {{ $ledgers[$i]->year }}</td>
                <td class="tbl-desc">{{ $ledgers[$i]->description }} </td>
                <td>{{ $ledgers[$i]->category}} </td>
                @if($ledgerCatType[$i]->type == "Expense")
                <td class="tbl-amount" style="color: #FF5349;">Php ({{ $ledgers[$i]->amount }})</td>
                @else
                <td class="tbl-amount" style="color: #3BC23E;">Php {{ $ledgers[$i]->amount }}</td>
                @endif
            </tr>
            @endfor
    </table>
</div>
<div class="pagination">{!! $ledgers->links() !!}</div>
```

**index.blade.php**

```
<div id="ledger-entry">
    @include('ledgers.entries')
</div>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::resource('ledger','LedgerController')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/ledger/fetch', 'LedgerController@fetch')->middleware('auth');
```

Comment: Can you check your `storage/logs`, that might show additional info of your error. If there's an error in your logs, paste it to your question.

Comment: I'm fairly new to Laravel. Is the error shown after the date and time?

Comment: Is this your actual code? The variable name you provide to the view is `$ledger` not `$ledgers` so you'd be getting an undefined variable error if this was your actual code

Comment: It is written in my index, I'm going to add the index.

Comment: @Ven sorry for the late response, yes, the logs have date/time in their name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay nevermind, I fixed it. I'm just going to post the answer here in case anyone gets stuck with it too.
The problem was my route, instead of using the `resource` I manually added the routes:

```
Route::get('ledger', 'LedgerController@index')->name('ledger.index')->middleware('auth');
Route::post('/ledger', 'LedgerController@store')->name('ledger.store')->middleware('auth');
Route::delete('/ledger/{id}', 'LedgerController@destroy')->name('ledger.destroy')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/ledger/fetch', 'LedgerController@index')->name('ledger.fetch')->middleware('auth');
```

I also edited my code for the `index()` and thus combining it with the `fetch()` method thus it now looks like this:

```
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $disableLedger = true;
        $ledgers = Ledger::orderBy('id', 'DESC')
            ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
            ->paginate(10);
        $ledgerCatType = DB::table('ledgers')
            ->orderBy('ledgers.id', 'DESC')
            ->join('categories', 'ledgers.cat_id', '=', 'categories.id')
            ->where('ledgers.user_id', auth()->user()->id)
            ->select('categories.type')
            ->paginate(10);
        $categories = Category::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->get();
        if ($request->ajax())
        {
            return view('ledgers.entries', compact('ledgers', 'categories', 'ledgerCatType', 'disableLedger'))->render();
        }
        return view('ledgers.index',  compact('ledgers', 'categories', 'ledgerCatType', 'disableLedger'));
    }
```